# Installing a software patch does not update all files

Tags: windows, installation, patch

Here is the scenario. I have version A of a software installed on my machine. A new patch is installed which makes the software version to B. Before installing the patch however, I did a backup of all files of version A.

Now, a new version of the patch is available (Again, this will bring the software to Version B). So, what i did, i replaced all the files of version B (Files that have been installed) with the backup of version A so as i can now re install the patch and bring the version to B again.

The problem is that after replacing my installed files of version B with version A backup and reinstalling the patch, the files are not being updated. In short after installing the patch, the version is remaining A.

Why i had to replace my installation with a backup of a previous version? That's the method employed where I work. I cannot change that.

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely if you'd simply installed the second patch, it would have been ok.

Check your file dates though.

Generally, installers will *never* replace a newer file with an older one. Depending on how you backed up the files from Version A, they may have gotten a newer date than the files from Version B that's supposed to replace them.

You could try using a "Touch" type utility to set the dates for the existing files in the installation to, say, a year ago, then run the patch again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know it would be simpler to installed the patch. The problem is that the general workflow where i work require that i backup the latest known working version before installing a new patch.

Comment: And if ever i have to reinstall a newer version of patch, i am required to restore the latest known working version before applying the patch.

Comment: As I mentioned, then, you'd want to make sure to set the file dates to whatever they were BEFORE you backed them up.